# How well MSSQL can survive a server hard reboot?

Tags: sql-server

Always hears people saying that hard resetting/rebooting may result in corrupted files. If the machine is running a database server such as MSSQL, the database may be corrupted as well. Does anyone shed some light on this? How well MSSQL can survive such a catastrophic situation?

Comment: zhe basic problem is, that when a file wrote occurs INSERT or UPDATE DELETE during the reboot the opraton will not be completed. so the data is correptedm also can such databse files be corrupted beyond repair.. So make backups backups backups. If such crashes occur frequently,. shorten the backup times

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "survive". The way the DBMS handles databases ensures that they are in a consistent state after recovery ran. Some changes may need a redo, some may need an undo. So data of transactions that weren't committed at the time of the fault is lost. (Unless there's a fault of the disks, if they're inaccessible, the DBMS cannot magically produce the data on them.)

Comment: Provided the files are not corrupted at the file system level, SQL Server, using write-ahead logging, is very robust.

Comment: Thanks all! Interesting though. This leads me to rethink what 'corrupted' means - (1) an incomplete data file that sql server doesn't understand anymore, (2) a physical damage to the underlying disk sector that data file can't be read anymore. For (1), per @David Browne comment below, SQL server has a very solid protection mechanism in place to mitigate it. For (2), it's all down to the underlying storage system, we can have RAID, SAN, etc.

Comment: Generally "corrupted files" historically referred to files that had data held in write buffers in memory and were not hardened to disk. This is never the case with SQL Server. Recently some modern *consumer* SSDs have large write-buffers which sometimes do not honour the buffer-flush requests and pretend data is hardened when it is not. This is why you should really have enterprise SSDs to run a database properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How well MSSQL can survive such a catastrophic situation?

Very well.  SQL Server uses Write-Ahead Logging, and forces its IO writes to be hardened to disk, and not cached in a way that wouldn't survive a reboot.

And it uses checkpointing to try to ensure that the database files never fall so far behind the log files that crash recovery exceeds the database's [Target Recovery Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/change-the-target-recovery-time-of-a-database-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=This%20topic%20describes%20how%20to%20set%20or%20change,an%20upper-bound%20on%20recovery%20time%20for%20this%20database.).

And while people don't typically just pull the plug on their servers, SQL Server runs on lots and lots of laptops and PCs which do this all the time.

Background:  [SQL Server Database Engine Input/Output requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/admin/database-engine-input-output-requirements) and [Description of logging and data storage algorithms that extend data reliability in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/admin/logging-data-storage-algorithms).

Comment: "*And while people don't typically just pull the plug on their servers...*" - True, but even with cloud services nowadays, it's not even uncommon for people to have SQL Server instances setup on servers that automatically spin up and spin down daily, as a way to manage their costs in the cloud. Theoretically those instances could have active transactions during server shutdown, and because of the resiliency of SQL Server, doing so doesn't inhibit their end goals. 

Answer (score 1):

The key here is how we define the word "survive". I can think of a few meanings/cases:

1. The database files are corrupted at the file system level. I.e., SQL server wrote "a", but the disk subsystem now returns "b". This is of course outside the reach of the database engine - it is a question for the OS, file systems and your SAN.
2. The database files are consistent, but from an earlier point in time (compared to when the shutdown happened). I.e., because of some caching at some level, I/O operations were lost (never hardened).
3. The database files are consistent, from the actual time when the shutdown happened. I.e., no I/O operations were lost.

3 is the easiest to address. SQL Server writes to the transaction log before it modifies the actual data (WAL, write ahead logging). Thanks to the recovery process (happens when you start SQL Server), SQL Server will give you a consistent state in the sense that all committed transactions now are persisted and the in-flight transactions has been rolled back.

2 means that we time-travelled to an earlier point in time. Say, 3 seconds earlier, for instance. Apart from that, it is identical to 3.

However, we have requirements for this to actually work. The most important is write ordering. The I/O operation need to be hardened in the same order as when they entered the disk subsystems. If your environment follow write-ordering, you can also do time-travelling according to 2 above.

There are of course lots and lots more than can be said about this, but the basics are pretty straight-forward.

Bob Dorr has written a classic chapter on this, which I'm happy to see is available on-line. This was 20 years ago, but the fundamentals are the same (some things has happened after this was written, like page checksum accelerated database recovery, indirect checkpoints etc, but those are just details in the big picture). So, if you're really interested, spend an hour or two reading this: https://bobsql.com/sql-server-i-o-basics-chapter-1/